# Is there a max width to the health bar?

Tags: dark-souls-3

[image: Screenshot of Dark Souls 3]

In Dark Souls 3, the health bar gets longer and longer the more HP you have.

**Is there a maximum width to the health bar?**

If you only leveled up Vigor, what would happen to your health bar? Is there a max? Would it just go off the screen? Would it create a second bar for your overfill health? Would it max out and then the mana/stamina bar are reduced to keep the ratios correct? Or is there just a roof to the health at some point, where the bar would not be able to go further only because you reached max possible health?

Comment: I can probably get a screenshot when I get home from work but I've left a text answer for now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From this video showing the (slightly outdated) maximum HP, the maximum *was* 2102 HP with 99 Vigor, a Life Ring +3, Ring of Favor +2, and being embered.

The HP bar at this value looked like this:

[image: max hp bar]

Based on the HP value of 2102, it is clear that the HP used to calculate the bonus from the Life Ring and Ring of Favor ***includes*** the bonus 30% from the player being embered.

However, since this video was uploaded, the Ring of Favor +3 was made available.

At 99 Vigor, you have 1400 base HP, so with ember and these rings, you would have:

1400 + 420 (Ember) + 182 (LR+3) + 109.2 (RoF+3) = **2111 HP**

Answer (score 6):

The bar will never become two bars, there is a cap on hp.
With diminishing returns vit 99 will grant the player 1400 base hp.

Life ring +3 is a further 10%.
Ring of favour +3 is 6%.
Finally the ember is 30%.

The maximum health is 2111.

That is the max hp (and width).

Edit: Turns out I was wrong and multipliers stack, sorry for the misinformation.

Comment: I think the lets play I'm looking at has 1000 base HP at this point. So the health roof would be a full screen of HP bar. Only thing missing would be a screenshot of this :p

Comment: The numbers here are wrong.

Comment: Are you certain that the percentages add instead of multiply?

Answer (score -2):

yes there is, if you use hacks to get an insanely high hp value it will only show the last ~2200 hp on the bar, anything hgher would be invisible, so if you get it it will look like you take no damage, once your current hp is below a certain Amount than it will show up, fp and stamina work this way too

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your answer would be greatly improved if you could provide a source or screenshot to support it.